# Replace items in enumerate environment

Tags: beamer, itemize

I'm trying to create a frame with an itemized list of items.

I would like those items to be replaced one at a time, with different content, at each frame.

Basically, the idea would be to display:

- At frame 1 only: item 1
- At frame 2 and onward: item 1 replaced with something else
- At frame 3 only: item 2
- At frame 4 and onward: item 2 replaced with something else
- At frame 5 only: item 3
- At frame 6 and onward: item 3 replaced with something else

Here's an example of the content of frame 1, 2 and 3:

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $x$
    \item $\lambda x \cdot x$
    \item $(x)y$
  \end{enumerate}
```

Here's an example of the content of frame 4, 5 and 6:

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item $\overbrace{x}^\text{\strut Variable}$
    \item $\overbrace{\overbrace{\lambda}^\text{\strut Symbole} \underbrace{x}_\text{\strut Paramètre} \overbrace{\cdot}^{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Séparateur}}} \underbrace{x}_{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Expression de retour}}}}^\text{Abstraction}$
    \item $\overbrace{\underbrace{(x)}_\text{\strut Abstraction}\quad \underbrace{y}_\text{\strut Paramètre}}^\text{Application}$
  \end{enumerate}
```

I tried many things before posting this message but I cannot find the proper compromise, there is always something going wrong.

The last example I came up with is:

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-> \alt<1-3>{$x$}{$\overbrace{x}^\text{\strut Variable}$}
    \item<2-> \alt<2-4>{$\lambda x \cdot x$}{$\overbrace{\overbrace{\lambda}^\text{\strut Symbole} \underbrace{x}_\text{\strut Paramètre} \overbrace{\cdot}^\text{\strut Séparateur} \underbrace{x}_\text{\strut Expression de retour}}^\text{Abstraction}$}
    \item<3-6> \alt<3-5>{$(x)y$}{$\overbrace{\underbrace{(x)}_\text{\strut Abstraction}\quad \underbrace{y}_\text{\strut Paramètre}}^\text{Application}$}
  \end{enumerate}
```

This snippet is almost ok and the problems are:

1. I found it extremely complex to build and maintain,
2. I wish I could reserve the space for the `overbrace` and `underbrace` in advance in the list

Do you have any clue on how I could fix all of this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions seems to be an x-y-problem.

> - At frame 2 and onward: item 1 replaced with something else

Instead of replacing item 1, it seems that your actual use case, adds stuff to item 1.

So instead of using overlays, you could adjust the colour of the different parts of your equation. This would avoid the elements appearing first from changing their position when the braces are added:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item<1-> \only<1>{\color{bg}}
    $\overbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{x}}^\text{\strut Variable}$\pause
    \item<3-> \only<3>{\color{bg}} 
    $\overbrace{\overbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{\lambda}}^\text{\strut Symbole} \underbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{x}}_\text{\strut Paramètre} \overbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{\cdot}}^\text{\strut Séparateur} \underbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{x}}_\text{\strut Expression de retour}}^\text{Abstraction}$\pause
    \item<5-6> \only<5>{\color{bg}}
    $\overbrace{\underbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{(x)}}_\text{\strut Abstraction}\quad \underbrace{\textcolor{normal text.fg}{y}}_\text{\strut Paramètre}}^\text{Application}$
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> 1. It display twice the last frame

remove the last `\pause` (all the other pauses are also unnecessary)

> 2. I wish I could reserve the space for the overbrace and underbrace in advance in the list

You can achieve this with a combination of the `\only` and `\visible` macros like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \only<1>{$x$}\visible<2->{$\overbrace{x}^\text{\strut Variable}$}
    \item \only<3>{$\lambda x \cdot x$}\visible<4->{$\overbrace{\overbrace{\lambda}^\text{\strut Symbole} \underbrace{x}_\text{\strut Paramètre} \overbrace{\cdot}^\text{\strut Séparateur} \underbrace{x}_\text{\strut Expression de retour}}^\text{Abstraction}$}
    \item \only<5>{$(x)y$}\visible<6->{$\overbrace{\underbrace{(x)}_\text{\strut Abstraction}\quad \underbrace{y}_\text{\strut Paramètre}}^\text{Application}$}
  \end{enumerate}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's complex and a bit counter intuitive, but it works, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz) who provided the solution.

In the end I modified a bit the order, I wasn't aware of the `\visible` command.

```
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \only<1-3>{$x$}\visible<4->{$\overbrace{x}^\text{\strut Variable}$}
    \item \only<2-4>{$\lambda x \cdot x$}\visible<5->{$\overbrace{\overbrace{\lambda}^{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Symbole}}} \underbrace{x}_{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Paramètre}}} \overbrace{\cdot}^{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Séparateur}}} \underbrace{x}_{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Expression de retour}}}}^\text{Abstraction}$}
    \item \only<3-5>{$(x)y$}\visible<6->{$\overbrace{\overbrace{(x)}^{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Abstraction}}} \underbrace{y}_{\mathrlap{\text{\strut Paramètre}}}}^\text{Application}$}
  \end{enumerate}
```